# Using aws aurora with laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have a migration that has `virtualAs`

```
 $table->string('subPrice')->virtualAs('price * quantity');
```

its translated to (MySQL):

```
 `subPrice` varchar(191) as (price* quantity)
```

But its showing syntax error, i had no problem with using mariadb, started having this problem when i start using aws aurora which uses MySQL 5.7.
Is it a problem with the MySQL 5.7?

Comment: Mind including the error text in your question?